# How do I go to another page with onClick?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./LogIn.css";

class LogIn extends React.Component{

    signUp(){
        window.location.replace("signup");
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                <header className="Trello-header">Trello</header>
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <div className="LogInBox">
                    <center>Log in to Trello</center>
                    <br /><br />
                    <center><input class="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email"></input></center><br />
                    <center><input class="Password" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"></input></center><br />
                    <center><button type="button" class="block">Log In</button></center><br />
                    -----------------------------------------------
                    <span>Can't log in?</span>
                    <span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                    <span onClick={this.signUp}>Sign up for an account</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default LogIn;
```

When I click, this.signUp method should redirect me to host:3000/signup page. How should I pull that off? When I click the text "Sign up for an account, it should redirect me to signup page.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just use links?

Comment: using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) or `window.location.href`.

Comment: `history.push('/page-name')` if you don't want to reload the page.   `window.location.href` if you want the browser to reload the page.

Comment: I did and when I clicked the text, the address becomes localhost:3000/signup but nothing else changed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href).

```
import React from "react";
import "./LogIn.css";

class LogIn extends React.Component{

    signUp(){
        window.location.href = "signup";
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                <header className="Trello-header">Trello</header>
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <div className="LogInBox">
                    <center>Log in to Trello</center>
                    <br /><br />
                    <center><input class="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email"></input></center><br />
                    <center><input class="Password" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"></input></center><br />
                    <center><button type="button" class="block">Log In</button></center><br />
                    -----------------------------------------------
                    <span>Can't log in?</span>
                    <span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                    <span onClick={this.signUp}>Sign up for an account</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default LogIn;
```

Comment: I did and when I clicked the text, the address becomes localhost:3000/signup but nothing else changed in the browser.